# why this error occurred ?Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular

Why am i getting this error? Please help me to solve this problem.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\Users\GniYes\Desktop\Angularjs2_Project\oshop\src'
>       resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\GniYes\Desktop\Angularjs2_Project\oshop\src'
>         using description file: C:\Users\GniYes\Desktop\Angularjs2_Project\oshop\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: C:\Users\GniYes\Desktop\Angularjs2_Project\oshop\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src)
>           using description file: C:\Users\GniYes\Desktop\Angularjs2_Project\oshop\package.json
>   (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory)
>             no extension
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case there was a missing component in app.module.ts